# How to get cloned value of Singleton's instance variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've some (a bit custom)singleton, that has `attr_reader :data`, which contains Hash.

I want to get this data and sometimes add there specific values.
But when I set data into variable, it turns out, that variable contains ***link*** on data, not the ***copy***.

**UPDATED**
Code of my 'singleton':

```
class Company
  FILE_PATH = "#{Rails.root}/config/company.yml"
  attr_reader :data
  def self.instance
    @instance ||= new
  end

  def self.path
    FILE_PATH
  end

  def save data
    File.open(FILE_PATH, 'w') { |file| file.write(data.to_yaml) }
    set_data
  end

  private
  def initialize
    set_data
  end

  def set_data
    @data = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load(File.read(FILE_PATH)))
  end
end
```

Usage example:

```
Company.instance.data[:bar]
 => nil 
foo = Company.instance.data
foo[:bar] = 'buzz'
Company.instance.data[:bar]
 => 'buzz'
```

How can I put copy of data to variable? I've tried `.dup` and `.copy`, but it didn't help.

(**UPD:** I've tried to use these methods on `instance`, not on `data`. My fault. Thanks everyone, who answered to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing something up.

```
class MySingleton
  include Singleton
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize
    @data = {a: 1, b: 2}
  end
end

foo = MySingleton.instance.data.clone
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
foo[:c] = 3
#=> 3
foo
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
MySingleton.instance.data
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

Comment: You're right. Maybe i gave not enough information, I've got a bit more complex case.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thanks, your example works correctly. It's my mistake, I've being using .clone on `instance`,  not on `data`

Answer (score 2):

I've tried with `.clone` and `.dup` and they both seem to work for me.

```
require 'singleton'

class MySingleton
    include Singleton
    attr_accessor :data
end

MySingleton.instance.data = {}
foo = MySingleton.instance.data
foo[:bar] = 'buzz'
puts foo # {:bar=>"buzz"}
puts MySingleton.instance.data # {:bar=>"buzz"}

MySingleton.instance.data = {}
foo = MySingleton.instance.data.dup # or .clone
foo[:bar] = 'buzz'
puts foo # {:bar=>"buzz"}
puts MySingleton.instance.data # {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of singleton pattern in Ruby has changed over time. Using `include Singleton` to implement explicit singleton classes has become fringe practice. Normally, you contruct an object eg. by calling `Object.new` and work with its singleton class `Object.new.singleton_class`, like this:

```
o = Object.new
class << o
  attr_reader :data
end
```

And you have a fully functional singleton with custom selector `#data`.